# Emulate older iOS versions on Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I downloaded latest XCode version for Mavericks. I'm looking forward to emulate older versions of iOS for wev development testing.

I followed instructions at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459399/ios-simulator-only-list-the-latest-ios-version-how-can-i-set-earlier-versions) posts where an answer recommends checking XCode's Preferences -> Downloads sections.

By going there is seems that I'm only able to download SDK's for iOS 6.1 and iOS 6.0.

Is there a supported way to get older emulators? I'm trying to avoid downloading other versions of Xcode due to very slow internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

iOS Simulator 5.0 and 5.1 do not work on Mavericks. See [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/911139#911139), granted you have a developer account with Apple.

> The iOS simulator does not duplicate some of the low-level parts of iOS. For example, it uses the host OS X's kernel instead of trying to virtualize the iOS kernel. The iOS simulator requires that these subsystems look sufficiently similar between the simulated iOS and the host OS X. When a new host OS X changes too much it can break old simulators. At that point somebody makes an engineering and cost decision to either update the old simulator or drop support for it.